# What algorithms or methods can be used in identifying object from images

Tags: algorithm, classification, image-recognition

My question is what kind of fast methods can be used to identify an object from a set of images. For example if I were writing a program, that has two inputs: A database of images, and a single image of an object, for example a persons face. Now the program is tasked to find all images that contain this object.

The problem here is that I understand that most of these classification systems that recognize objects need to be trained by lots of data before they are accurate, but are there faster methods to do quick scans? After some hits in this application there could maybe be an option for user to confirm hits, and those could maybe be used for further refining of the results.

Edit: To clarify: What I'm looking for is something that where the system sees something for the first time, and from that one image it tries to match other images from database. For example tracking someone between multiple security cameras with dead spots in between: The camera sees only once (only a few 
 good frames) the subject, and from that it should be able to identify the same subject from other camera. Or showing an object on one camera, and then a robot must find the object from environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you search something different than machine/deep learning you should have a look to "**Computer Vision**". There's a ton of related scientific stuff.
[Cf. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision)

Otherwise machine learning contains **learning**. Your neural network or whatever must be trained - that's how it works. The more it is trained the faster and accurate it will be. Being faster needs more training or implies accuracy sacrifice.

Besides

> After some hits in this application there could maybe be an option for user to confirm hits, and those could maybe be used for further refining of the results.

That's also already partly how it works.